# i am not able to link pages in django my code is correct .What else i need to do?

Tags: python, django, linux

in `urls.py` file my code is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("<str:name>", views.index ,name="index"),
]
```

in `views.py` file my code is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item


# Create your views here.
def index(response,name):
    ls=ToDoList.objects.get(name=name)
    return HttpResponse("<h1>%s</h1>" %ls.name)
```

path also added in urls.py-mysite

error showing page not found

Comment: What URL do you use to access the page? And what is your project structure?

Comment: i want to make a page that will data from database. so i had made these codes in views.py                                                       
       from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item


# Create your views here.
def index(response,name):
 ls=ToDoList.objects.get(name=name)
 return HttpResponse("<h1>%s</h1>" %ls.name)  when i am running python manage.py  and get adress of local host it is showing page not found. insead of showing the error

Comment: Do you just use `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`)? If so, it is not found, because you only have `127.0.0.1/<name>` defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your app urls.py into your project urls.py like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
  path("", include("your_app.urls")),
]
```

Comment: this is already done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running this from an app, don't forget to add your app to your settings.py file as well, such that:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app' # add the name of your app here
]
```

and your project `urls.py` file should also look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')) # add your app name here as well
]
```